# Viewing ArcGIS Pro layer as JSON to illustrate CIM (Cartographic Information Model)

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro, json, cartographic-information-model

In order to work with the Cartographic Information Model (CIM) from ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro I am interested in viewing the JSON for a particular layer.

In a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=8wgt8bKD0Ww) from Esri's 2019 Developer Summit:

> Product Engineer, Jeff Barrette, demonstrates new and improved tools
>   for map creation automation, to include features: advanced symbology,
>   arcpy.mp, and the Cartographic Information Model (CIM).

At the 2:58 mark of that video, the presenter shows a JSON file for an ArcGIS Pro layer as background for working with the CIM.

How was such a JSON file obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a .lyrx file and open in your fave text editor to see the JSON.

```
{
  "type" : "CIMLayerDocument",
  "version" : "2.3.0",
  "build" : 15850,
  "layers" : [
    "CIMPATH=map/new_group_layer2.xml"
  ],
  "layerDefinitions" : [
    {
      "type" : "CIMRasterLayer",
      "name" : "Shaded Relief_dem.tif",
      "uRI" : "CIMPATH=map/shaded_relief.xml",
<snip...>
```

I don't have ArcGIS Pro >= 2.4 to test how to convert an arcpy layer [CIM Definition](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) to JSON so I can't answer if it's possible to do this in code.

i.e

```
import arcpy
import json

aprx_path = "path\\to\\your.aprx"

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_path)
for map in aprx.listMaps():
    print("Map: " + map.name)
    map_def = map.getDefinition()  # <-- Get the CIM definition

    # Do something with map_def object to create a JSON object.
```